# AVPlayer Item get a nan duration (invalid)

Tags: ios, objective-c, avasset

I am using `AVAsset` class and passed url. But it does not provide the duration. I only get `nan`.

```
CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
float audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
 AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] options:nil];   // info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] is url(file url) here. You should pass your url here

   CMTime videoDuration = asset1.duration;

  float videoDurationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration);
```

and make sure that your url is file url!!